# .htaccess prevent folder access that are subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

in my webhost every time I create a new subdomain it creates a public-access folder in my *html_public* folder, and I want to block the access to those folders with a fake 404 error (using the default one if it's possible, I'm using this to set the default 404 error: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`) but allowing to access if it is the subdomain.

For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/blog/ -> Should show a 404 Not found error
http://blog.mydomain.com -> Should allow the user to access
```

Both of them are the **same** folder *html_public/blog*

I tried to add a **.htaccess** file in *blog* folder with this code:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

But it does not allow the access (logic), it does not matters if it is folder or subdomain.

And this one:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/* /404.php
```

But like other, it redirects all to a 404 error, instead of only the direct access to the folder and allowing the access to the subdomain.

*Note: I saw other questions that redirects from folder to subdomain, I need to show a 404 error.*

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can use a condition, like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /blog.+  RewriteRule ^(.*) /404.php`. Check **[this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)** to more info

Comment: What if url be like `/blog/some-post/`? It should also be redirected?

Comment: Hi @RahilWazir, any URL should be redirected, it must show a fake 404 error (like does not exists, even if it does exists), and yes everything on `http://www.mydomain.com/blog/`, folder, and all files and subfolders, but it must work with `HTTPS` and `HTTP`, and also with and without `www`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/ /404.php [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Hi @JonLin I can't test it right now, does it works with `HTTPS` and without? and, does it works with and without `www`?